# Graph Facebook API giving cURL error when trying to post to a user's wall

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, curl

All,
I have the following code:

```
<?php
require_once 'facebook.php';

$app_id = "1234";
$app_secret = "45678";

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
 'appId' => $app_id,
 'secret' => $app_secret,
 'cookie' => true
));

$result = $facebook->api("/me/accounts?access_token=123456");
foreach($result["data"] as $page) {
    echo $page["name"];
    $page_id = "81918";
    if($page["id"] == $page_id) {
        $page_access_token = $page["access_token"];
        break;
    }
}
$args = array(
    'access_token'  => $page_access_token,
    'message'       => "I'm a Page!"
);
$post_id = $facebook->api("/$page_id/feed","post",$args);
?>
```

When I execute this, I get the following message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught CurlException: 77: error setting certificate verify locations: CAfile: D:\My Documents\xampp\htdocs\website/fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt CApath: none thrown in D:\My Documents\xampp\htdocs\website\base_facebook.php on line 853

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error. Can anyone help me out and let me know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** I'm running XAMPP on my localhost here if that helps anyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Didn't realize that I needed to get the facebook certificate. The certificate can be found here:

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/src/fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt

Just put this in the same directory that you're base_facebook.php file is in.

Answer (score 4):

You need to have a certificate in the same folder as `base_facebook.php`.

Comment: Do I have a certificate? I have base_facebook.php and facebook.php both in the same folder where I'm trying to execute this script from

Comment: but you must have certificate in folder with these files. this certificate is in php sdk

Comment: Mihalicka Do you mean like an SSL certificate? This is the first I've heard of needing a certificate to execute this cURL functionality?